# multiphp php.ini no effect

Tags: php, php-7, php-5.6

I'm running multiple php versions 5.6, 7.1 (default), 7.2.
To change php values in 7.1 or 7.2, i go to

> /etc/php/7.x/apache2/php.ini

.
The problem comes with php5.6. There no apache2 folder inside

> /etc/php/5.6

.
When I run `$ php5.6 -i "phpinfo()" | grep "php.ini"`
I get

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/5.6/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini
```

I've tried changing *upload_max_filesize* and *post_max_size* inside /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini but it has no effect in phpinfo. Also tried set in htaccess:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 24M
php_value post_max_size 32M
```

but is doesn't work either.
Keeps showing default value when installed:

```
post_max_size 8M
upload_max_filesize 2M
```

I always restart server *service apache2 restart*.
I'm setting php version for domains that use another version beside default 7.1 via vhost.

php5.6 Eg:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    # Apache 2.4.10+ can proxy to unix socket
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
</FilesMatch>
```

Any ideas what might be the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

With fpm I needed to restart php, `service apache restart` had no effect:

```
service php5.6-fpm restart
```